# position attribute in whishlist.xml does not work

Tags: magento-1.9, toplinks, reorder

I would like to reorder the wishlist in top links through xml file not editing the

```
app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\Block\Links.php
```

Wondering why below code does not work?

```
  <default>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <block type="wishlist/links" name="wishlist_link" />
            <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>wishlist_link</blockName><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: Can you please put under which block you are calling this `action` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because there is no function **`addLinkBlock`** available in `app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\Block\Links.php` this file/Class nor in it's parents class.

You can use **`AddLink`** action which you can find in `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Template/Links.php` file.

You can use following

```
<default>
        <reference name="top.links">
              <action method="addLink" translate="label title"><label>Wishlist</label><url>wishlist</url><title>Wishlist</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        </reference>
</default>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Since I want this changes only in one of the store views. Changing the Links.php affects all other themes as well! Any hint?

Comment: @Zinat Check i have updated answer

Comment: You can use store handle in your layout xml. Put your changes in that store handle. So changes will affect particular store only. Check [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76840/layout-update-handle-per-storeview)

Comment: Thanks Rohit. May you please help me with these <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
                <action method="addCartLink"><prepare/><urlParams/><position>20</position></action>
                <action method="addCheckoutLink"><prepare/><urlParams/><position>15</position></action>

            </block> too?

Comment: What you want to do? Can you please tell?. If you want to set custom position then don't use `<block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">`. Direct call your action with `addLink` function within `<reference name="top.links">`. You can check my answer example

Comment: Where you called this action? Under which block?

Comment: In checkout.xml, under <reference name="top.links">
            <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">

Comment: Remove `<block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">`. ---  Your code should be like this `<default>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title"><label>Wishlist</label><url>wishlist</url><title>Wishlist</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title"><label>Cart</label><url>checkout/cart</url><title>Cart</title><prepare/><‌​urlParams/><position>15</position></action>
        </reference>
    </default>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37159/discussion-between-zinat-and-rohit).